# How to require a module with and without arguments in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

**My Query:**

How to differentiate and thus handle with and without arguments in required module?

**In Detail:**

I have written a module which will console a message in color (passed as argument). If nothing is passed, then default color (say white) to be picked.

```js
require('my-module');    //should print 'Hello World' in white (default) color.
```

```js
require('my-module')('red');   //should print 'Hello World' in red color.
```

**File Content (my-module.js):**

```js
// First Call
displayMessage('');

module.exports = function(color){
  // Second Call
  displayMessage(color);
}

// Main function
function displayMessage(clr){
  ... console in provided clr 
}
```

1. Only First call happens for **require('my-module')** with default color.
2. Both the calls happen for **require('my-module')('red')** once with no/default and next with red color argument.

If I move the first function call inside separate module.exports:

```js
module.exports = function(){
  // First Call
  displayMessage('');
}
```

It is not called at all on **require('my-module')**.

> If I can get an indicator to differentiate between the two calls, it might be possible to add conditions accordingly.

Comment: Of course it isn't called at all when the function is the export. The **function** is being exported, not the *result of calling it*. `const exportedFn = require('my-module'); exportedFn(); exportedFn('red');`

Comment: This is a BAD interface.   You can make `require('my-module')();` display white and `require('my-module')('red');` display red, but you should not and probably cannot really do it the way you are asking because the first thing that happen is the module is loaded and THEN, the function it's called is returned.  You don't know when the module is loaded whether there will be a function call coming soon or not.  There are hacks with timers to try to figure it out, but it's a BAD design.  Don't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I understood it, will change my approach.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove line,

```
 // First Call
displayMessage('')
```

Whenever you require the module this will be loaded and called . if you want default method with default value then either make it conditionally for no arg OR just export the method itself .

```
  module.exports = function() {
        // First Call
        displayMessage('');
  }

   module.exports = function(color){
        // Second Call
        displayMessage(color);
  }

  // Main function
  function displayMessage(clr){
        ... console in provided clr 
   }
```

EDIT:

As per comments, it is not possible to call no argument constructor from everywhere . So you need to go with a flag for sure .

```
   var argCall = false;
   module.exports = function(color) {
         // Second Call
        argCall = true;
        displayMessage(color);
    }

    if (!argCall) {
          // First Call
          displayMessage('');
    }

    // Main function
   function displayMessage(clr){
         ... console in provided clr 
   }
```

Now it will work for without calling,

```
   require('my-module')      // will  go through FIRST CALL

   require('my-module')('red')      // will go with SECOND CALL only
```

Comment: You are right Bilal. But how to make it conditional? That's what I am looking for - a parameter I can use to differentiate. If you can mention the skeleton code here, that would be helpful.

Comment: just you could use if else .. otherwise i have edited answer that has multiple constructor methods

Comment: I have tried this already. For no arguments, exported function is not called at all.

Comment: you need to call that. like    `require('my-module')()`

Comment: That would work Bilal. :) 
I don't just want a workaround to make my code work, but also want to know if **require('abc')** and **require('abc')() / require('abc')('input')** are feasible together and how.

Think of a scenario where this no-argument function is being used already across the modules. I want existing code to work as well as when argument is provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202086/discussion-between-noopur-tiwari-and-bilal-siddiqui).

Answer (score 1):

require('my-module') , just load the file or function , will not call any methods;

require('my-module')(); , will call the function once , with undefined argument;

require('my-module')('red'); , will call the function once , with 'red' argument;

Comment: That's not happening Sara. 
As I have mentioned **require('my-module')('red');** is calling the function twice, first with no argument and then with red.

Comment: @noopur because you have, in the definition of the file, a function call. So no matter what, when Node first parses the file and makes it available, your function is called once. Then, if the result of `require` is invoked with call operator, the module.exports (in your case a function) is called with whatever arguments were supplied by the `require`-ing file (in your cases, none and then later 'red').

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch, yes I need to change my approach.  
Now that the question is no more relevant, should I delete it?